# Parametric equations of a subspace

Tags: vector-spaces, parametrization, invariant-subspace

The exercise tells me that given the set

$$W=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5) \in \mathbb{R}^5 : x_1+x_2=x_3-x_4 ,  x_2+2x_3=x_4-2x_5\}$$

I should

1. Prove that $W$ is a vector subspace of $\mathbb{R}^5$ (which I think I did good, I just applied the 3 conditions ($W$ different than zero//closed by addition//and closed by scalar multiplication. If that's somehow wrong, please tell me, because my teacher has done it in a totally different and weird way)

And the hard one, the one that's making me ask this

2. Give the parametric expression of the subspace. I think maybe the kartesian equation would work here, but I can't figure out how, I only have one resolved example on $\mathbb{R}^4$. So if any of you guys could help me, I can't thank you enough.

Comment: You might need more parameters than in your $\mathbb R^4$ example, but the process is the same.

Comment: @Martín Vacas Vignolo thanks for fixing my answer, but what exactly did you do? Did you use latex? How can I learn how to type in my text so you don't have to help me any longer?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have 2 constraints put on top of $\mathbb R^5$ this sub-space should have dimension 3.

$x_1 =s\\
x_2 = t\\
x_3 = u$

From the first constraint
$x_4 = -s - t + u$

And plug these into the second constraint

$x_5 = \frac 12 x_4 - \frac 12 x_2 - x_3\\
x_5 = -\frac 12 s - \frac 12 t + \frac 12 u  - \frac 12 t - u\\
x_5 = -\frac 12 s - t - \frac 12 u $

$W = \pmatrix{1\\0\\0\\-1\\-\frac 12}s + \pmatrix{0\\1\\0\\-1\\-1}t +\pmatrix{0\\0\\1\\1\\-\frac 12}u$

Comment: Thank you very much, until "x5=12x4−12x2−x3x5=−12s−12t+12u−12t−u" I understand it way better now, but I can't figure out what did you do at the last step. I know you're using R3 identity, but how exactly?

Comment: Isolate $x_5$ in the second equation above.  Then express $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ in terms of $s,t,u$ as you have already solved.

Comment: I got that, what I don't understand is the final step when you put W=... I know you're using the identity matrix, but I don't get how or why

Comment: $W = (x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5) = (s,t,u,-s-t+u, -\frac 12 s, -t, -\frac 12 u)$  Then I factored out the $s, t, u$ components $(1,0,0,-1,-\frac 12) s,$ etc.